# convert variable in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wrote a piece of simple code that I dont to find what the problem.

the code is:

```
           var sortSecurities="SELECT * FROM securities";
           int total=0;
           var value="";
           foreach(var row in db.Query(sortSecurities))
           {
               value=row.lastGate;
               total=Convert.ToInt32(value)*100;// here the problem with compilation.. 
               db.Execute("INSERT INTO holding(IDgrossPortfolio,IDSecurity,totalHolding,units,buyGate) "+"VALUES (@0,@1,@2,@3,@4)",row.category,row.number,total,"100",row.lastGate);
           }
```

what the problem with the convert?

the error is:

> Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: What is the value for the variable `value`?

Comment: the type of value is string but it represent a number,becouse of that I want to convert it to string to enable Multiplication...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`value` does not hold a value that can be converted to Int32. If you could do some debugging and see what the value of it is from `row.lastGate`, you might see what the problem is.

Also, not sure what is returned by `db.Query(sortSecurities)` (or really what kind of object `row.lastGate` is), but you can also try to change `value=row.lastGate;` to `value=row.lastGate.ToString();`

Comment: thanks.. but what I need to do for isolate just the value to variable for convert it?

Comment: You need to make sure that *each* `row.lastGate` from your query contains a proper value that can be converted to an integer. If you are using visual studio, you can set a breakpoint on that line and "Start with Debugging" to see what each value is at run time. Or you can query the database directly and see what `lastGate` is for each row.

Comment: row.lastGate represent a number but stored in the database as nvarchar, so I know Certainty that it number... what I need is some method that allow me to convert the value to int...

Comment: If you are sure each `row.lastGate` actually represents a number (and isn't empty or null), you can try to change `value=row.lastGate;` to `value=row.lastGate.ToString();`

Comment: @ofirhgy What exactly is returned by `db.Query(sortSecurities)`?

Comment: It returned record of details of stocks but look in the answers here I found a nice solution and I wrote it befor couple of minutes.. thanks you about the intention...

Comment: I meant what type of object is returned, but nevermind, glad you figured it out.

Comment: @ofirhgy This is one reason why you shouldn't store numbers as strings.  While you can most likely fix this particular issue, your problems would be solved much more completely if you could change your database such that the numbers were stored as actual numbers.

Answer (score 1):

you can use try parse to check if the value actually contains a number

```
  int total;
  bool result = Int32.TryParse(value, out total);
  if (result)
  {
      db.Execute("INSERT INTO holding(IDgrossPortfolio,IDSecurity,totalHolding,units,buyGate) "+"VALUES (@0,@1,@2,@3,@4)",row.category,row.number,total,"100",row.lastGate);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `value` isn't successfully being parsed by `Convert.ToInt32()`

Alternatively, consider using `Int32.TryParse()` and validate if the data is indeed the type of data you're expecting.

```
int result;
if(Int32.TryParse(row.lastGate, out result))
{
    //row.lastGate was a valid int
    total = result * 100;
}
else
{
    //row.lastGate wasn't a valid int
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you for all... I try now and found elegant answer.

**Like I wrote in the comments, becouse I know that the value of row.lastGate
represent a number I don't need to check it.**
So I try this and it works:

```
var sortSecurities="SELECT * FROM securities";
           int total=0;
           double value=0;
           foreach(var row in db.Query(sortSecurities))
           {
               value=Convert.ToDouble(row.lastGate);
               total=Convert.ToInt32(value)*100;//100 is default
               db.Execute("INSERT INTO holding(IDgrossPortfolio,IDSecurity,totalHolding,units,buyGate) "+"VALUES (@0,@1,@2,@3,@4)",row.category,row.number,total,"100",row.lastGate);
           }
```

Probably I needed to change the value first of all to double and then to int 
Becouse when I try to change it directly to int the Compiler did'nt interpret the 
string right, becouse of the dot in the number (type double).

thanks about the the intention..